# What is meant by transaction 'pinning'?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, terminology, replace-by-fee, pinning-attack

What is meant by the term 'transaction pinning'?

Answer (score 16):

Transaction pinning happens when:

1. I broadcast a transaction that signals opt-in RBF
2. the transaction does not get confirmed because the feerate is too low
3. someone else broadcasts a new (child) transaction spending one of the outputs of my transaction
4. I now can't bump the fee on the transaction unless I include a fee greater than that of the combined original transaction + the child transaction ([BIP 125](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0125.mediawiki), rule 3).

If the child transaction in (3) is large (eg a commercial service sweeping up lots of transaction outputs), then the total fee that I'd need to pay for a valid RBF would be very large.

In this scenario, my original transaction has been 'pinned' by the child transaction.

Russell O'Connor has proposed [changing the RBF policy rules](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2018-February/015717.html) to alleviate this problem.

Comment: Wouldn't the child transaction trigger Child Pays For Parent in most cases?

Comment: @SamJones - that depends. Child Pays For Parent is where a child transaction has a higher _fee-rate_ than the parent, thus increasing the average fee-rate across the parent-child package and making it more attractive for a miner to include both in a block. In the example above, the child transaction might have a lower fee-rate, so it doesn't increase the average fee-rate of the package. Instead it is a large transaction with a high _absolute fee_. Any replacement transaction for the parent needs to exceed the absolute fee of the replaced transactions.